# Problemas com a indentação do Python no Geany

Tags: python, indentação, geany

Desde que mudei de IDE ( passei do Pycharm para o Geany ), comecei a ter muitos problemas com o erro: "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation".

Gostaria de saber uma forma de resolver esse problema constante, uso apenas tab para a indentação, sem espaços ou qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: Posta exatamente o que dá problema pra gente ver, certamente está misturando as coisas. Em Python acaba sendo melhor usar espaços, a não ser que a pessoa seja disciplinado e saiba bem como achar o problema quando ocorre, o que não é seu caso.

Comment: Você consegue ver quais caracteres são tabs e quais são espaços ou eles aparecem todos invisíveis para você?

Comment: Victor - Aparecem todos invisíveis.

Comment: Maniero - https://pastebin.com/1RSwLR2h

Comment: Você disse que só usa tab, só que quase tudo está com espaço. Só de o pastebin converteu

Comment: Como vejo se são espaços ou tabs?

Comment: Praticamente toda boa IDE tem opção de mostrar "caracteres invisíveis" (por exemplo, mostrando espaços como pontinhos centralizados e tabs como setinhas). Habilitar esta opção pode ajudar a identificar e resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2):

O geany usa tab por padrão na identação.

Altere em Edit > Preferences > Editor > Indentation de Tabs para Spaces.

O Python usa, por convenção, 4 espaços para identar(padrão do Pycharm), e não deve ser misturado tab e espaço para evitar erro de compilação.

Comment: Ah, deve ter sido isso então, pois " transferi " o código do Pycharm para o Geany

Comment: O pycharm segue a convenção do PEP8, acusando o uso indevido de tabs no código.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente o Python apresenta esses erros pois o compilador se baseia muita na indentação. É recomendado não ficar usando muito o copiar e colar pegando código de outros cantos ou sites pois quando se faz isso eles podem vir com o espaçamento diferente quando você inserir na IDE de sua  preferência.

Você pode usar também o Sublime Text como uma via diferente para fazer os seus códigos pois ele é um bom editor para esse tipo de coisa. Eu também mudei do Pycharm e atualmente uso o Sublime para programar em Python pois ele apresenta uma boa indentação.

Comment: Entendi, a propósito, não copiei e colei o código não, estou estudando Pygame e " desenvolvendo " o mesmo jogo que do curso, para testes.

Answer (score 0):

Olhando o código que você postou em um editor que permite visualizar tabs e espaços de forma que não fiquem invisíveis (Notepad++):

[image: visualizado]

Todo o resto do arquivo está identado com espaços. Recomendo a sempre identar com espaços, que dão menos dor-de-cabeça.

Comment: Okay, passarei a indentar com espaços.